# Composer installs Extensions to /vendor but Magento path is /app/code Fails to Load

Tags: extensions, magento2.4, composer

I installed a magento extension via composer require

I can see the files in **/vendor** but when I click on the extension from the admin panel it gives me an Exception that the Class does not exist as the link to the extension is set to **/app/code**. If I copy the **/vendor** folder to **/app/code** it works but then I get errors if I use **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** about the extension already being defined in **vendor**

There must be a path set somewhere telling magento to look for extensions in **/app** where I do have some webkul extensions installed.

What should I do?